# Setting up Allegro 5 with Xcode on Yosemite

Tags: c++, xcode, ide, allegro5

I’ve recently started learning how to use Allegro 5 in C++ and I’m currently having trouble getting it set up in an Xcode project. I’ve gotten accustomed to the basics of Allegro 5 using Vim, but now I’d like to create a game to help strengthen my understanding of C++ & to learn some game programming concepts.

I have looked online for guides on how to set Allegro 5 with Xcode but they all seem to use earlier versions of Xcode which I’ve tried to follow to no avail  (I’m not familiar with Xcode). Also, as I’m a self-taught programmer, I haven’t found any guides explaining the basics of IDEs on the internet* (e.g. what’s a build target? What’s a build phase?).

In vim, I’ve been using `g++` with the following code in a makefile to compile my Allegro 5 code:

```
all: main.cpp ship.cpp
    g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/userName/Desktop/C/Asteroids/include -L/usr/local/lib -lallegro -lallegro_dialog -lallegro_image -lallegro_main -lallegro_primitives example.cpp -o example.exe
```

Does anybody know of any good detailed guides on how to set up Allegro 5 on Xcode?

*I have used IntelliJ & Pycharm before but I’m not familiar with all the different settings that an IDE has, especially when one needs to add 3rd party libraries to their project.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XCode... But maybe you can adapt the Visual Studio Guides on the wiki [here](allegro.cc) to use XCode instead of VS. Most of the terms used should have their equivalence in XCode